# Advaita: What is Nididhyasana?

Tags: advaita

Who first used the term nididhysana? Shankaracharya or Ramana Maharshi?

Is nididhyasana meditation or mere contemplation?

If its meditation, then how is it different from Patanjali's meditation techniques?

If its contemplation, then how does constant deep thinking gives a person moksha from cycle of rebirth?

If its reminding oneself that he is Brahman, by repeating the mahavakyas, then can such reminders and repetition of mahavakyas bring moksha from cycle of rebirth?

Comment: Nidhidhyasana is a scriptural term not coined by Adi Shankara or any other ... I believe it is found in various scriptures with reference to Advaitic methods. For the moment you can see this from Shiva Gita (see under 13.4)-- https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/shiva-gita-study/d/doc425976.html

Comment: Went through the passages from the link you provided. It says there Nididhyasana is contemplation of what is learned or heard. Any idea, how can mere contemplation give moksha or how can assuring oneself repeatedly he's not the body/mind,  give moksha?

Comment: I am not trying to answer your whole Q .. it has many parts of which I just tried to clarify regarding one which asks "who coined the term?" It's a scriptural term.

Answer (score 6):

You have many questions few among which are answered as follows:

Nididhyasana is a scriptural term. So neither Adi Shankara nor Ramana Maharshi was the first person to use it. The term can be found in Puranas.

From Devi Bhagavtam 7.34:

> ...... then works become beneficial and helping to Jñânam. (Therefore
> the Jîvas should take up both of these.) Others say that this is
> impossible owing to their contradictory natures. The knots of heart
> are let loose by Jñânam and the knots are knit more by Karma. So how
> can they be reconciled? They are so very diametrically opposite.
> Darkness and light cannot be brought together, so Jñânam and Karma
> cannot be brought together. Therefore one ought to do all the Karmas
> as best as one can, as enjoined in the Vedas, until one gets
> Chittas'uddhi (the purification of one's heart and mind). Karmas are
> to be done until S'ama (the control of the inner organs of senses),
> Dama (the control of the outer organs of senses), Titiksâ (the power
> to endure heat and cold and other dualities), Vairâgyam (Dispassion),
> Sattva Sambhava (the birth of pure Sattva Guna in one's own heart)
> take place. After these, the Karmas cease for that man.
>
> Then one ought to take Sannyâsa from a Guru (Spiritual Teacher) who
> has got his senses under control, who is versed in the S'rutis,
> attached to Brahma (practising the Yogic union with Brahma). He should
> approach to him with an unfeigned Bhakti. He should day and night,
> without any laziness, do S'ravanam, Mananam, and **Nididhyâsanam**
> (hearing, thinking and deeply realising) the Vedânta sayings. He
> should constantly ponder over the meanings of the Mahâvâkyam "Tat Tyam
> Asi." "Tat Tyam Asi" means Thou art That; it asserts the identity of
> the Supreme Self (Brahma) and Embodied Self (Jîvâtmâ). When this
> identity is realised, fearlessness comes and he then gets My nature.

Another instance where it is found in Puranas is in [Shiva Gita](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/shiva-gita-study/d/doc425976.html):

> 13.4. Means for rise of Knowledge.
>
> Rāma wanted to be enlightened on how does sacred knowledge about Śiva
> arise in a mortal and means in that matter. Lord, further, explains
> the way to acquire the purest knowledge, by his grace, to the great
> Rāma. Abandoning all attachment to entire creation, including ones own
> kith and kin, and having faith in the scriptures and longing for
> vedantic wisdom, with gifts in hand one should approach a learned and
> realized preceptor and please him with services and hear with intense
> concentration (śravaṇa) about the essence of Upaniṣads in the form of
> Mahāvākyas and reflect (manana) on them and do constant contemplation
> **(nididhyāsana)** on oneself Abhijñāna Śākuntala the Supreme Self and by
> grace of god, all past karmas gets burnt in the fire of knowledge and
> the devotee do not acquire any subsequent karmas and becomes a
> realized one; a Brahma-Jñāni becomes himself Brahman. After
> realization one happens to incur whatever sin, does whatever
> meritorious deeds, great or small, he is not affected by such sin or
> merit. Such a person is Jīvan-mukta. When all the desires in a person
> are controlled and conquered, then the mortal turns into immortal.[4]
> Release is known Abhijñāna Śākuntala the destruction of the knots of
> heart caused by ignorance.

According to Vedanta Sarah of Sri Sadanandayogindrasaraswati, the Sadhana of an Advaitin comprises of the following (he has given a flow chart at the end of the book):

> - 1. One must forsake Nishiddha Karmas (acts forbidden by scriptures) and  Kamya Karmas (acts that are performed with certain goals in
>      mind).
> - 2. With due performance of Nitya Karmas (obligatory acts like Sandhyavandanam etc) and Naimittik Karmas (occasional rites),
>      Prayaschittas (penances), the aspirant needs to attain Chittasuddhi
>      (purification of mind) and Mumukshtatva (a desire for Moksha).
> - 3. Guropodesha (Initiation of Guru's teaching)
> - 4. Shravana (Hearing the Mahavakyas and Guru's teachings). Understanding their meanings using a six fold method (Upakrama,
>      Upasamhara, Abhyasa etc.).
> - 5. Manana (contemplating and realizing the meaning through arguments).
> - 6. Nididhyasana
> - 7.Samadhi

The definition of Nididhyasana that is given in the book is mentioned in verse 192 and is as follows:

> vijAtiya-dehAdi-pratyaya-rahita-advitiyavastu-sajatiya
> pratyaya-pravAhah nididhyAsanam || 192
>
> Depriving the mind from any external thoughts of Brahman (like body
> etc.), when mind and thoughts are focused on only the Adavitic nature
> of Brahman is called Nididhyasana.

Amrita commentary on this verse is as follows:

> Nididhyasana is uninterrupted Dhyana (meditation). No other thought
> processes (Chitta Vritti) must arise in it. After Shravana (hearing)
> and Manana (contemplation of what has been heard), the mind gets
> fixated into one form (Swarupa) and when no other forms arise in the
> mind other than that Swarupa, that is called Nididhyasana. By
> continuous discrimination through "Neti Neti" (not that, not that
> method) what remains is the Consciousness (Chaitanya) and to fix the
> mind only on that Consciousness is called Nididhyasana.

According to Advaita, by performing Nididhyasana, the aspirant attains Samadhi (which can either be Nirvikalpa or Savikalpa) and which results in self realization.

EDIT:

I have found an English copy of the Vedanta Sarah book that I have used in this answer [here](https://ampgc.ac.in/admin/upload/documents/econtent/vedantsar.pdf).

The definition of Nididhyasana is found on page 83 of the PDF.

[image]

In my case the book is in Sanskrit-Bengali and here the book is in Sanskrit-English. Also the translators are different.

Comment: Sorry i had to post multiple questions in my original post as i wanted to have a full understanding of it. And thanks for this detailed answer. Now i have a couple more questions after going through this answer. ;) According to Sri Sadanandayogindrasaraswati's Vedanta Sara, verse 192 and its amrita commentary, Nididhyasana is uninterrupted Dhyana, with no thoughts/vrittis, and fixing the mind on a Swarupa? ... My question is, whose form or swarupa are we speaking here? Is it saguna brahman's form? ... We can't possibly  fix our mind on nirguna brahman's swarupa, since IT has no form.

Comment: The form is that One Chaitanya that remains after using the Neti Neti method. Basically it is difficult to describe that Swarupa in words.@TheCrimsonUniverse That form is the only target of Nididhyasana

Comment: Finally in your post, the swami says, after neti neti, what remains is the consciousness/chaitanya and one needs to fix his mind on IT ... Again, is it really possible to fix our mind on the formless consciousness or nirguna nirakara brahman? ... I mean after rejecting everything during neti neti, all we are left with, is a blank wall, devoid of thoughts. We are aware of this blankness during deep sleep, as told by swami sarvapriyananda as well. Do you think one should fix his mind on this blankness and meditate instead? Is this actually Nididhyasana as per the amrita commentary?

Comment: Yes it's difficult but that's what Advaita teaches ... According Tantras one must start with form endowed meditation because it is virtually impossible to meditate on the formless. @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: One last thing. May i know whose translation of Sadananda's vedanta sara you have quoted above? And is the amrita commentary too part of the same book? Thanks.

Comment: It's a book published by Ramkrishna Mutt Calcutta. Translation and commentary by Swami Amritatvananda.@TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: I searched the whole web but couldn't find any English copy of this book. Neither on ramakrishna website nor on amazon. It would be great if you could share a link, which i can visit and purchase the physical book. If no physical book available, then even a free ebook would do. Thanks again.

Comment: See my update ... I just searched once on google and got this book @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: Since Amritatvananda's book is only available in bengali, I'm guessing its 'you' who did the English translation on amrita commentary in your original post ... If such is the case, then i must say that 'your' translation is really good. ;)

Comment: Yes I have translated the translation part as well as the commentary part from Bengali ... Not sure if it is good or not ... someone else might have done better .. I actually find it difficult when I have to translate from Bengali to English because these translators use complicated words .. I might need to consult a dictionary .. so it's additional headache when I have to answer using hard copy of Bengali books @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: I can read bengali, if only the bengali is simple and easy to understand. Same with English. The language needs to be simple so that any mind can grasp it. :) I really like Ramakrishna's teachings as well. They're all in simple language.

Comment: Oh so you can read Bengali .. Yes, Ramakrishna's teachings use very simple language unlike these translators who always prefer to use highly complicated terminologies :D@TheCrimsonUniverse

Answer (score 1):

Answering Q1

Nididhyasanam is an upanishadic term ,
(may occur in prakarana granthas(texts)  but isn't coined in them.)

Saadhana Chatustaya(SC) sampathi advocated by HH Adi shankara is the precursor for Shravana Manana  Nidhidhyasanam(SMN) .

It is futile to embark on SMN without self-introspecting on own SC sampathi,( If one can't achieve SC, Bhagavad Gita suggests Karma Yoga.)

Yamaha and Niyamaa are supposed to be the stepping stone for yoga path.

From what I know, shravana is getting to know of (listen) from vedantic scriptures , (so here the listener is never misinformed), Mananam is feasibility study that removes doubts , Nidhidhyasanam is turning it into experiential reality.

But Nidhidhyasanam on mahavakyas (not an object of any knowledge)  is far-fetched and tougher than any upaasana .

> Brihadaranyaka Upanishad (2.4.5)
> आत्मा वा अरे द्रष्टव्यः श्रोतव्यो मन्तव्यो निदिध्यासितव्यो मैत्रेयि,आत्मनो व अरे दर्शनेन श्रवणेन मत्या विज्ञानेनेदं सर्वं विदितम् ||"
> Ãtmã vã are drashtavyaha shrotavyo mantavyo nididhyãsitavyaha...(sage yagnyavalkya)
> The Self, my dear Maitreyi, should be realized – should be heard of, reflected on and medtated upon;by the realization of the Self, my dear, through hearing, reflection and meditation, all this is known."

> Panchadhashi
> (Praakarana grantha, Swami vidhyaranya)
> chapter 1 verse 54
> ittha.n vaakyais tad arthaanusandhaana.n shravaNaM bhavet.h .yuktyaa sambhaavitatvaanusandhaanaM manana.n tu tat.h ..
> When the ideas that we have gathered through hearing and studying from a preceptor are made to enter our feelings by deep reflection on the same, and when these ideas that have become practically part of our nature by way of deep investigation—when concentration and reflection become inseparable from us—we become absorbed in them to such an extent that we think only these ideas. Our very outlook changes in terms of these ideas, and the whole world is envisioned by us in terms of these noble ideas only. Nididhyasana is this condition where knowledge acquired through study and hearing, and made one-pointed by reflection and investigation, becomes part of one's nature by delving into one's own heart and making the knowledge a part of one's being. This leads to deep meditation.(translation by Swami krishnananda)

> vivekachudamani
> verse 364(Praakarana grantha/ Shankaracharya )
> śruteḥ śataguṇaṃ vidyānmananaṃ mananādapi |
> nidiṃdhyāsaṃ lakṣaguṇamanantaṃ nirvikalpakam || 364 ||
> Reflection should be considered a hundred times superior to hearing, and meditation a hundred thousand times superior even to reflection, but the Nirvikalpa Samadhi is infinite in its results.

Comment: So as per the quotes of krishnananda in your post, nididhyasana is the condition of making the aquired knowledge part of one's own nature ... Lets say, i spend 10 years under a genuine guru learning everything. Then after reflecting and investigating on those knowledge, i finally apply them in my daily life. I'll start considering all strangers and friends as none other than myself. I'll see no distinction between a rock, plant, or a murderer ... Is this vision of oneness, a symptom of a person who  practices nididhyadana? or did i completely misunderstood what krishnananda said?

Comment: without introspecting one's own   natural tendency of dispassion for all worldly things , akin to a adult^s dispassion for toddler toys(known as vairagyam in SC) , how may ever years one may study under a teacher , may not experience a natural inclination towards this process..Afaik traditional gurus in past did not simply  accept anyone as  disciple.A true jnani has unlimited compassion for all living being , be it scorpion or a  murderer, and has risen above all the dualities, If you are interested Swami  Vivekananda s works and  life experience s may throw more light on this

Comment: Yes its true, that knowledge from a guru alone isn't enough. Ond needs to reflect on those teachings and practice dispassion. But that's not what i wanted to know in my earlier comment. I wanted to know what krishnananda (in your post) meant. According to him Nididhyasana is absorption of the knowledge learnt from sravana, and making that knowledge part of one's life. I only wanted to know what are the symptoms of a person, who makes that knowledge part of one's life, or in other words, the symptoms of a man who practices nididhyasana? Does he percieve oneness? Is that his symptom?

Comment: Symptoms experienced by the realised person (Brahma-Jnana anubhavam ) is not  verbalised in any scripture(as far as I know) but certainly it may  explain it thru  analogies like like wave-ocean etc. ..Nevertheless,  Arjunas question in BG 14.21(kair lingais..) might relate to your q. whose ans. is in BG14.22,14.23(prakasham cha..) Still if this is obscure probably the recorded experiences of contemporary sages like vivekaananda, who ve attained that stage may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Ramana Maharshi is very recent. So of course Adi Shankaracharya used it much before.
But, noone coined the term. The term has scriptural basis.

In the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad ([2.4.5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117950.html))

> आत्मा वा अरे द्रष्टव्यः श्रोतव्यो मन्तव्यो **निदिध्यासितव्यो**
> मैत्रेयि,
>  आत्मनो वा अरे दर्शनेन श्रवणेन मत्या विज्ञानेनेदं सर्वं
> विदितम् ॥ २.४.५ ॥
>
> > The Self, my dear Maitreyī, should be realised—should be heard of,
> > reflected on and meditated upon. By the realisation of the Self, my
> > dear, through hearing, reflection and meditation, all this is known.
>
> Adi Sankara's commentary-
>
> > Therefore ‘the Self, my dear Maitreyī, should he realised, is worthy
> > of realisation, or should be made the object of realisation. It should
> > first be heard of from a teacher and from the scriptures, then
> > reflected on through reasoning, and then steadfastly meditated upon.’ Thus only is It realised—when these means, viz. hearing, reflection and meditation, have been gone through. When these three are combined, then only true realisation of the unity of Brahman is accomplished, not otherwise—by hearing alone.

---

### Regarding the apparent sameness & differences -

Quoting from this book - The Method Of The Vedanta A Critical Account Of The Advaita Tradition by Swami Satchidanandendra (Translated by A.J. Alston)

> Chapter 3.
>
> ##### [56. THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN PRESCRIBED SYMBOLIC MEDITATIONS (UPASANA)  AND SUSTAINED MEDITATION ON THE ABSOLUTE (NIDIDHYASANA)](https://archive.org/details/the-method-of-the-vedanta-a-critical-account-of-the-advaita-tradition-swami-satchidanandendra/page/n183/mode/2up)
>
> It has been explained how the monk who has attained through
> dispassion to genuine adoption of the life of wandering mendicancy
> must necessarily carry out the discipline of hearing  the texts and
> pondering over them regularly and continually  until he gains
> immediate vision of the Self, He who does not  attain this immediate
> vision merely from hearing, must carry  out further regular hearing,
> supported by pondering over the  meaning. **Weak and mediocre
> candidates,'however, must also  perform sustained meditation**
> (nididhyasana, cp. T.N. at M.V,  53, intro.).
>
> Sustained meditation, like the unbroken meditation implied  in the
> prescribed symbolic meditations, is a piece of action.  Hence it is
> sometimes called meditation (upasana). Yet such  symbolic meditations
> as 'Woman is the sacrificial fire'  (Chand.V.viii.l) are differently
> defined.
>
> **Upasana (as contrasted with nididhyasana) means maintaining a stream of  identical images of which the form is (not dictated by one's
> knowledge of any reality but) prescribed in the Veda. Nididhyāsana, on
> the other hand, means fixing the mental gaze  on the principle of
> reality to determine its true nature, like  one examining a Jewel.**
>
> **A candidate practising meditation in the form of upasana  must select
> one of the meditations laid down for attaining to the Lord as
> associated with attributes, and maintain the same  image in his mind,
> according to the dictates of the Veda, until he has obtained
> immediate vision of the object of his  meditation. For meditation
> realizes its true end when it is  used as a means to direct vision.
> But its reward is attainment of the Absolute in its lower form at a
> later time (i.e.  after death) in the World of Brahma**. Here there is
> enjoyment  of the same experience as the Lord. And at the end of the
> world-period the final metaphysical knowledge will arise, and  there
> will be deferred release in company with Brahma. Such  is the teaching
> of the Veda.
>
> **The aim of the one practising sustained meditation (nididhyasana)
> is different. He tries to attain direct vision of  reality (here in
> this very world) by turning his mind away  from all else. And there is
> the difference — as against upasana — that after the rise of
> knowledge nothing further remains to be done.** It is this sustained
> meditation that is  referred to at Katha Upanishad I.ii.l2 by the name
> 'Adhyatma  Yoga’. **In the Gita it is sometimes called ’Dhyana Yoga'
> (e.g.  XVI11.52)**. In the Mandukya Karikas it is called ’restraint of
> the mind’ (G.K.III.41, etc.). Its nature is described there  in that
> latter work. **Everywhere its result is described in  the same way as
> right metaphysical knowledge, and from this  comes immediate
> liberation (sadyo-mukti).**

So basically, it looks like that Nididhyāsana is the precursor practise to that of the Patanjali's Samādhi.

Further,

> Chapter 7.
>
> [124. Point 6](https://archive.org/details/the-method-of-the-vedanta-a-critical-account-of-the-advaita-tradition-swami-satchidanandendra/page/n403/mode/2up)
>
> **Awakening to immediate knowledge of the supreme Self depending on no external factor is called Nididhyasana.** It is
> mentioned after seeing and heairing to show that they culminate
> in that.... One's first knowledge of the Self is through
> hearing, and then one ponders over what one has heard. When
> heauring and pondering are complete, one comes to have immediate knowledge of the Self....
>
> **Because the use of the word
> 'Nididhyasana' (lit. 'sustained meditation') might lead the
> hearer to suppose that meditation was meant, the Upanishad
> deliberately uses the term 'immediate intuition' (vijnana) as
> a synonym for it at **Brhadaranyaka (2.4.5)** to show that meditation is not here meant. I already mentioned earlier how
> meditation amd other practices are a means to immediate experience. But immediate exprience does not exist for the
> sake of anything else. It is taught to be just liberation
> attainment of the final goal of all. (B.B.V. II.iv.217 9 220,
> 233-U)**.
>
> Chapter 8
>
> [154. Point 6](https://archive.org/details/the-method-of-the-vedanta-a-critical-account-of-the-advaita-tradition-swami-satchidanandendra/page/n503/mode/2up)
>
> Sustained meditation (nididhyasana) means fixing the mind on the
> content of the metaphysical texts of the Veda as supported and
> mediated by pondering. **Nididhyasana cannot here mean dhyana in the
> sense of upasana, for the practice of enjoined meditations for karmic
> merit would be useless in the present context** (cp. B.Sid. p.l5^j
> M.V,'98,1,; ad fin,). In the text 'The Self should be seen*
> (B^‘had.II.iv.5)» the 'seeing of the Self refers (not to an act
> performed in response to a command but) to immediate awareness of the
> unity and sole reality of massed Consciousness, bereft of all
> manifestations of plurality, arising as a result of having fixed the
> attention on the content of the metaphysical texts.
>
> Chapter 12
>
> [259. Point 16](https://archive.org/details/the-method-of-the-vedanta-a-critical-account-of-the-advaita-tradition-swami-satchidanandendra/page/n879/mode/2up)
>
> **In Sri Sankara's Commentary on Gaudapada's Karikas the term
> 'nididhyasana' (sustained meditation) is interpreted as a synonym for restraint of the mind, practised by the middling class
> of students to achieve the dissolution of the mind into the
> Self.**

Thus, the Shankaracharya's definition of Nididhyāsana is implied for the weak-minded practitioner, as an intermeditate to the Nirvikalpa-Samādhi.

As regards -

`"If its contemplation, then how does constant deep thinking gives a person moksha from cycle of rebirth?"`

The answer is in the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, quoted in the begining -

To paraphrase -

> The Self comes to be seen through the disciplines of hearing, pon¬
> dering and sustained meditation resolutely pursued. Right  knowledge
> of the Absolute as the sole reality only dawns when  these three
> disciplines of hearing, pondering and sustained  meditation are fused
> into one, and not otherwise, for example  through hearing alone'
> (Brhad Up 2.4.5).

So, it's a step by step ladder, and doesn't happen suddenly, by just following one of step.

---

<sup>P.S. Your last part of the question, should be a standalone question in itself.</sup>

Comment: In your post, you have quoted from the book - The Method Of The Vedanta... by Swami Satchidanandendra (Translated by A.J. Alston) ... There under chapter 7 the author says, that nididhyasana or sustained meditation should not be understood as actual meditation just because the word 'meditation' has been used but rather it should be interpreted as immediate intuition (vijnana) as per Brhadaranyaka 2.4.5 ... Now i would like to know a few things.

Comment: ... I would like to know how does this immediate intuition takes place? Does it take place right after manana (pondering on the teachings)? ... Lets say, i ponder over the teachings for a month or more while taking a stroll in the park, while lying in my bed, while travelling in a crowded bus etc. ... After that will i get the sudden nididhyasana (immediate intuition) experience while i'm in the midst of an indoor/outdoor activity? ... or does nididhyasana (immediate intuition) involves sitting in a lotus posture, calming the mind, breathing techniques etc.?

Comment: All this stuff is to be performed under a Guru, not by oneself. Some people may be able to do it by themselves, and may have "sudden-intuition", but not all, those are exceptions of exceptions. There's no time limit to a spiritual sadhana, it may be sudden or take its own course as per the 'innate & inherent' spirituality of the 'sAdhaka'. @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: Right. One needs to practice it under a guru. I'm just enquiring online as much as i can to have a basic knowledge on what the advaitins believe in or what they usually practice. Its not that i want to start practicing them right away :) ... You said in your original post, under swami satchidanandendra's chapter 11 quotes, that as per Shankaracharya, nididhyasana is intermediate to nirvikalpa samadhi? From your understanding on these matters, how would you distinguish nididhyasana from nirvikalpa samadhi? I mean what is the difference between these two, as per your knowledge in these matters?